# Getting Sublime Text 2 to treat jsm the same as js

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'd like to have sublime text 2 treat `.jsm` files the same as it does `.js` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "treat jsm files same as js" by Syntax highlighting then Open the jsm file in SublimeText. Then click on View → Syntax menu, select "Open all with current extension as.." & select Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that the ApplySyntax plugin did the truck.
https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax

Once you have it installed, add the following to your User settings for the ApplySyntax plugin (this is found in the Preferences menu, then select Package Settings-->ApplySyntax-->Settings - User)

```
"syntaxes": [
    {
        "name": "JavaScript",
        "rules": [
            {"file_name": ".*\\.jsm$"}
        ]
    }
]
```